# Source for midpapi20.jar

Tags: eclipse, java-me

Where can I find the `midpapi20.jar` source files?

I started J2ME applications development using eclipse and I'm not able to view the javadoc of the classes. I tried with NetBeans and it asks me to `attach sources` for `midpapi20.jar` but I can't find them.

It's very annoying not being able to find such informations on google, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use (if the licence attached to midpapi20.jar permits you) jd-gui.exe which is a java decompiler. This will yield a good approximation to the original source files although enums, string switches and <> will be messed up.

Comment: The javadoc comments will not be presserved. I want to be able to view the source like using Java 1.7 in eclipse